# Geometry problem help

Tags: geometry

[image]

The given figure, $ABCD$ represents a square of side $6$ $cm$. $F$ is a point on $DC$ such that the area of the $\triangle{ADF}$ is one-third of the area of the square. Find the length of $FD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Square Area = $36$, Triangle ADF Area = $\frac{1}{2}(36)=12 = \frac{1}{2}$base $\times$ height = $\frac{1}{2}\text{base}(6)$. So when is, $\frac{1}{2}\text{base}\ 6=12$? Verify that it is when base$=4 \Rightarrow \text{FD} = 4$.

Comment: But the answer at the back of the book is 4 cm.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. The one third should of been one half.

Comment: No problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Hint*: The area of the triangle is $$\tfrac{1}{2} \times 6 \times |\overline{FD}|\ \text{cm}^2=\tfrac{1}{3} 6^2 \ \text{cm}^2.$$

Comment: It'll be $\frac{1}{3} 6^2 $

Answer (score 0):

This one is straight calculation. Let us do it a slightly different way. Draw a line through $F$ perpendicular to $CD$, and meeting $AB$ at $G$. Then rectangle $FDAG$ has area $\frac{2}{3}$ of the area of the square.

Since the height of the rectangle and the square are the same, the base of rectangle $FDAGG$ is $\frac{2}{3}$ times the base of the square.